# Mock Symfony Form 'query_builder' with Mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, mockery

I'm struggling to mock the `query_builder` option in my Symfony form tests, I've tried using the `m:on(function () {})` but to no avail...

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class MyCustomForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $userToken = 'this will be a TokenInterface object';

        $builder->add('field1', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'My Label',
            'class' => 'AppBundle:MyClass',
            'query_builder' => function (MyClassRepository $repository) use ($userToken) {
                return $repository->setUserToken($userToken)->orderBy('alias.column_1');
        ]);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is test that the `setUserToken` and `orderBy` methods are called on the mocked object.

```
namespace tests\Unit\AppBundle\Form;

class MyCustomFormTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // Setup test class etc...

    public function testBuildingTheForm()
    {
        $this->builder->shouldReceive('add')
            ->once()
            ->with('field1', EntityType::class, [
                'label'         => 'My Label',
                'class'         => 'AppBundle:MyClass',
                'query_builder' => m::on(function ($closure) use ($userToken) {
                    // Test calls
                    // Test a mock method call with($userToken)

                    return true;
                },
            ]);

        $this->testClass->buildForm($this->builder, []);
    }
}
```

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
1) Tests\Unit\AppBundle\Form\MyCustomFormTest::testBuildingTheForm
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_0_IteratorAggregate_Symfony_Component_Form_FormBuilderInterface::add("field1", "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType", array('label'=>'My Label','class'=>'AppBundle:MyClass','query_builder'=>'object(Closure)',)). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Dave Marshall, I came up with a solution!

Test Class:

```
namespace tests\Unit\AppBundle\Form;

class MyCustomFormTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // Setup test class etc...

    public function testBuildingTheForm()
    {
        $this->builder->shouldReceive('add')
            ->once()
            ->with('field1', EntityType::class, m::on(function ($options) use ($userToken) {
                $this->assertSame('My Label',          $options['label']);
                $this->assertSame('AppBundle:MyClass', $options['class']);

                $mockRepository = m::mock('AppBundle\Repository\ MyClassRepository');
                $mockRepository->shouldReceive('setUserToken')->with($userToken)->once()->andReturnSelf();
                $mockRepository->shouldReceive('orderBy')->with('alias.column_1', 'ASC')->once()->andReturnSelf();

                $options['query_builder']($mockRepository);

                return true;
            }));

        $this->testClass->buildForm($this->builder, []);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed `Mockery::on` like that, so you'll need to bring it up a level, something like this:

```php
public function testBuildingTheForm()
{
    $this->builder->shouldReceive('add')
        ->once()
        ->with('field1', EntityType::class, m::on(function ($options) use ($userToken) {
            $this->assertEquals('My Label', $options['label'];
            $this->assertEquals('AppBundle:MyClass', $options['class'];

            // whatever you need to test with $options['query_builder']

            return true;
        }));

    $this->testClass->buildForm($this->builder, []);
}
```